# How can I show QtyOnHand field(in IN402000) to the PO detail grid in PO301000

Tags: acumatica

How can I show QtyOnHand in IN402000 to the PO 301000 detail grid?

Answer (score 1):

The POLine DAC already has a "QtyAvail (Qty on Hand)" field. You would simply need to create a customization project, add the screen, navigate to the Grid: Transactions and add the Control for the field to the screen & publish.

If you need to add the field to PO Line and the Quantity Available from INItemStatus would suffice you could add it with:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.IN;

public class POLine_Extension : PXCacheExtension<POLine> {
  [PXDecimal]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty Avail", Enabled = false)]
  [PXDBScalar(typeof(
    Search<INSiteStatus.qtyAvail,
      Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<POLine.inventoryID>,
        And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<POLine.siteID>>>>))]
  public virtual decimal? QtyAvail { get; set; }
  public abstract class qtyAvail : IBqlField {}
}
```

Then the PXDBScalar fields have their values set when the DAC is Selected. There's probably a better way this could be done, but to populate the field as lines are added & updated to the PO within a POOrderEntry graph extension, you could handle the FieldUpdated events for the InventoryID and SiteID to execute a function that retrieves the Qty Available using basically the same BQL and sets that value to the DAC extension field.

```
public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    public virtual void POLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateQtyAvailable(sender, e);
    }
    public virtual void POLine_SiteID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateQtyAvailable(sender, e);
    }
    private void UpdateQtyAvailable(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;
        POLine row = (POLine)e.Row;

        foreach(INSiteStatus siteStatus in PXSelect<INSiteStatus,
            Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>,
              And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.siteID>>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, row.InventoryID, row.SiteID))
        {
            sender.SetValueExt<POLine_Extension.qtyAvail>(row, siteStatus.QtyAvail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a QtyAvail field in POLine DAC. Also the QtyOnHand field from IN402000 is computed at runtime and could have a different value than other QtyAvail fields.

Comment: your code work to show the Qty Avail in PO detail grid but when I add more new line in the grid after I choose the Inventory ID the value of the Qty Avail column is still 0.00. Can you help me with the event to automatic update Qty Avail after select Inventory ID. Step by step with the code please thanks you

Comment: I've edited the original answer with an addition for this.

Comment: It's work but one more thing please when I change the UOM column in the  PO detail Grid I want the Qty Avail divide by the value of the Conversion Factor (Qty Avail/Conversion Factor ( Conversion Factor in Distribution => Stock Item => General Stetting => Unit of measure => Grid).

Comment: That's something completely different. Please start a new question for it and complete/accept this question and answer.